# redirigir al detalle luego de insertar registro laravel

Tags: laravel

estoy usando en mi controlador una funcion que mediante una transaccion me isnerta datos en dos tablas diferentes, me funciona bien pero requiero que una vez hecho el commit  me lleve a una vista especifica (segun el id que se ha creado en la transaccion) que mostrara el detalle de lo insertado.

Tengo la ruta asi: `Route::get('bodegas/logistica/ser/{id}', [BodegaLogisticaController::class, 'detIngresoParaSeriado'])->name('bodega.logistica.detIngresoParaSeriado');`

La funcion que retorna la vista (recibiendo supuestamente el id del insert) asi:

```
  public function detIngresoParaSeriado($id){

        $detalles = DetIngresoMaterial::all()->find($id);

        return view('bodega.logistica.detIngresoSeriado', compact('detalles'));

    }
```

y la funcion store:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        try {
             //comenzamos transacion
             DB::beginTransaction();

             //guardamos primeramente en la tabla ingreso_materials
             $ingresoMaterial = new IngresoMaterial();
             $horaActual = Carbon::now('America/Santiago');
             $ingresoMaterial->fecha_ingreso = $horaActual->toDateString();
             $ingresoMaterial->num_guia_despacho = $request->get('num_guia_despacho');
             $ingresoMaterial->observaciones = $request->get('observaciones');
             $ingresoMaterial->usuario_id = $request->get('usuario_id');
             $ingresoMaterial->proveedor_id = $request->get('proveedor_id');
             $ingresoMaterial->servicio_id = $request->get('servicio_id');
             $ingresoMaterial->save();

             //detalles del ingreso de materiales
             $material_id = $request->get('material_id');
             $bodega_id =$request->get('bodega_id');
             $cantidad = $request->get('cantidad');
             $servicio = $request->get('servicio_id');
             //$ingreso_material_id = $request->get('ingreso_material_id');

             //ingreso de serialziacion del material a ingresar a bodega

             $cont = 0;
             while($cont < count ($material_id)){
                 $detalleIngreso = new DetIngresoMaterial();
                 $detalleIngreso->ingreso_material_id = $ingresoMaterial->id;
                 $detalleIngreso->material_id = $material_id[$cont];
                 $detalleIngreso->bodega_id= $bodega_id;
                 $detalleIngreso->servicio_id= $ingresoMaterial->servicio_id;
                 $detalleIngreso->cantidad = $cantidad[$cont];
                 $detalleIngreso->save();
                 $cont=$cont+1;
             }
             DB::commit();

             Alert::success('Registro Añadido con exito!!!', 'El registro de ingreso de material ha sido almacenado con exito...');
             //return redirect()->route('bodega.logistica.detIngresoParaSeriado')->with($ingresoMaterial->id);
            return view('bodega.logistica.detIngresoSeriado', $ingresoMaterial->id);

             //return redirect()->route('bodega.logistica.index')->with('success','Nuevo material ingresado con exito...');

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //throw $th;
            DB::rollback(); //SI NO SE PUDO INSERTAR EN LA PRIMER TABLA, SE DESHACE TODO
        }
            //return view('bodega.logistica.detIngresoSeriado')->with($ingresoMaterial->id);
            //return view('bodega.logistica.index');
      }
```

Al ejecutar hace el insert pero la llamada a la vista del detalle no funciona, quedo en blanco la pantalla

Saludos a todos

Comment: @BetaM hola, no resulta porque la ruta espera el id

Comment: return redirect()->route('bodega.logistica.detIngresoParaSeriado')->with(['id' => $detalleIngreso->id]); me dice : Missing required parameter for [Route: bodega.logistica.detIngresoParaSeriado] [URI: bodegas/logistica/ser/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como puedes leer en la [doc. sobre *helpers*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-route) el método `route()` puede recibir como segundo argumento un array asociativo de parámetros.

Entonces dado lo anterior, podemos dejar tu código así:

```
return redirect()->route('bodega.logistica.detIngresoParaSeriado', ["id" => $ingresoMaterial->id]);
```

Te recomiendo revises la estructura del método `route()` en la siguiente ubicación: *vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php* que nos muestra algo así:

```
function route($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = true)
```